# Ag-grid disable sorting globally

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

In my **Angular** project I'm using **Ag-grid-ng2**

I want to disable sorting functionality for the whole Ag-grid.
I can do it *column wise* but didn't find any way to do it *globally*.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[enableSorting]="false"` to your `ag-grid` tag.

**e.g.**

```
<ag-grid ... [enableSorting]="false" ...>
```

[Find an example here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#example-sorting-order-and-animation)

Of course you would need to do this in every place where you use `ag-grid`

Also.. taken from the docs as well

> Turn sorting on for the grid by enabling sorting in the grid options.

I assume that you can also turn **off** the sorting that way, you would need to get a reference to the `gridOptions` and then

```
gridOptions.enableSorting = false;
```

on your `ngOnInit()`

Comment: What version of ag-grid are you using?

Comment: Actually one of my office colleagues did it and she has found a workaround for this. Thanks for your time @maury844.

Comment: @MalinduSandaruwan you can always share it as your own answer so people finding this question in the future can know how to do it :). Thank you!

Comment: No, we have avoided the problem. And I'm sure it has no use to the community ☺

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I already read the document on ag-grid site

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best possible way ! it is dynamic too..

```
this.columnDefs.forEach(col => {
 col.sortable = false
})

this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
```

Solution works with latest Ag-grid version :)